# How do I organise my Xamarin.Forms solution?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project. When I create Xamarin.Forms portable solution I get one Portable project and four platform projects for iOS, Android, Windows8.1 and WindowsPhone 8.1 respectively.

I have all the UI pages and logic codes in a portable project and all platform specific calls in each platform project. Now referring to the [Xamarin Architecture](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_2_-_architecture/), we can have six application layers.

To achieve this what changes would I need to do in my project structure?

Will I have to separate out UI page and put it in separate Project and separate project for Business logic? 
I am new to Xamarin so would like to know expert's view.

Comment: First of all you don't to follow strictly the layers presented in that document, as that is only a general suggestion. Secondly, the first 4 layers (Data Layer to Service access (if you have it...)) should be included in the common part of your code, while the remaining (practically UI code and platform specific code) should be in the Forms project. The platform specific projects (ios, android...) should be used only for very specific customizations.

Comment: By 'Common part of your code' do you mean a portable project? And what will be forms project? In my case all the common part including common UI is in the portable project.

Comment: What you are doing is already fine in my opinion. If you want to have a bigger separation, you can leave all your UI in the portable project, and move all the common stuff (access to the database, business logic...) to a new project, that will be common to all possible platforms. So you could have, for instance a structure with: App.Common, App.Forms, App.iOS, App.Android...

Comment: I will go ahead as per your suggestion @markusian

Comment: App.Common would be a class library portable project?

Comment: App.Common would be what in the Xamarin documentation is called a PCL

Answer (score 1):

If you have to implement the same project for Web/Desktop, how do you go about it? You would use the same implementation here too.

Basically, in Xamarin.Forms solution the Portable Class Library project is the entry point to your application. The iOS, Android, Windows 8.1 and WindowsPhone 8.1 projects are used to package your UI in the Portable Class Library project for each platforms. So you don't have to rewrite UI for each platforms.

All your DTOs, Data Access Layer and Algorithms will be directly referenced into the Portable Class Library project.

Comment: So the structure as suggested by @markusian of having App.common, App.portable, App.iOS, App.Anroid.. will be the best structure.

Comment: @Arti yes, I think so.